# How do I submit a NOTAM?

Tags: air-traffic-control, faa, notam

I (a hypothetical person) am involved in an activity like laser light shows, model rocket launches, fireworks displays, or construction which I think might be important to pilots. How can I submit this information to the FAA so that they can issue a [NOTAM](http://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When I have had to file NOTAMs for skydiving demonstration jumps, I just called AFSS (1-877-4-US-NTMS) and asked to file.  The folks at Lockheed are way more helpful than the Feds used to be and will walk you through the process, but it is still good to have your information together before you call.  At a minimum you need a description of your activity, altitudes in MSL, times in zulu, and a location.  Location should be in reference to an aiport or nav aid ("Within one nautical mile of the BFE airport", or "27nm from the BADGER VOR on the 340 radial, for a radius of 2 nm").  If the activity requires authorization, you will also need to have that squared away before calling.